# fgrep -f that output also the matched string from the string_file

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I'm using the command:

```
fgrep -wf string_file.txt searching_file.txt > myoutput.txt
```

(in the following example, for simplicity I only present very few values for the sake of example, but please assume there could be many more)

The `-f` is used for specifying a string_file for basing on the search in the searching_file.txt

The `-w` is used for performing a word-based search, and to eliminate fractions-matching between the two files.

string_file.txt contains:

```
DEFB106A
ZXFGH456
ANKRD23
FNTDRE2433
```

searching_file.txt contains:

```
1553970_s_at    carboxyl ester lipase (bile salt-stimulated lipase) /// bile salt-activated lipase
1552411_at  defensin, beta 106A /// defensin, beta 106B, DEFB106A /// DEFB106B
1555890_at  olfactory receptor, family 2, subfamily A, member 20 pseudogene /// OR2A20P /// OR2A9P
1553366_s_at    ankyrin repeat domain 23 /// ankyrin repeat domain 39, ANKRD23 /// ANKRD39  
1554894_a_at    pterin-4 alpha-carbinolamine dehydratase/dimerization cofactor of hepatocyte PCBD2
1555286_at  cyclin-dependent kinase-like 1 (CDC2-related kinase), CDKL1
```

The output of this run is: myoutput.txt

```
1552411_at  defensin, beta 106A /// defensin, beta 106B, DEFB106A /// DEFB106B
1553366_s_at    ankyrin repeat domain 23 /// ankyrin repeat domain 39, ANKRD23 /// ANKRD39
```

Since the searched string (the string from string_file that is used for performing the search) is often found to be 'buried' at the middle of the line, for example: "DEFB106A" is in the middle of the line:

```
1552411_at  defensin, beta 106A /// defensin, beta 106B, **DEFB106A** /// DEFB106B
```

- I am basically interested to assign each of the output lines with its own original string from the sting_file, so that I'll be able to easily identify which of the searching strings is yielded a match in the searching_file.txt file.
- Or, in other words, the idea here is to EXTRACT the matching string from the original line where it is buried. At the same time, I would also need the entire context (so I am interested in outputting also the entire matched line, as it contains values that I need such as the probeset ID, for example, 1552411_at).
- The idea here is also to allow us to identify which of the strings from string_file.txt had a match in the searching_file.txt!

So for example, as an output I would love to get something like this:

```
1552411_at  defensin, beta 106A /// defensin, beta 106B, DEFB106A /// DEFB106B    DEFB106A 
1553366_s_at    ankyrin repeat domain 23 /// ankyrin repeat domain 39, ANKRD23 /// ANKRD39  ANKRD23
```

OR

```
DEFB106A 1552411_at defensin, beta 106A /// defensin, beta 106B, DEFB106A /// DEFB106B    
ANKRD23 1553366_s_at    ankyrin repeat domain 23 /// ankyrin repeat domain 39, ANKRD23 /// ANKRD39
```

Note, that many cases like ZXFGH456, and FNTDRE2433 (from the string_file) are not yielding any match.

Comment: I can see how I'd do it in Perl; I'm not sure there's a simple solution with `grep`.

Comment: yes, i wish to avoid programming here, if possible...

Answer (score 3):

You could post-process the output of `grep` with `sed` like this — assuming you have Bash and [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
$ grep -Fwf string_file.txt searching.txt |
>     sed -f <(sed 's%.*%s/.*\\(\\<&\\>\\).*/\\1 \&/%' string_file.txt) 
DEFB106A 1552411_at  defensin, beta 106A /// defensin, beta 106B, DEFB106A /// DEFB106B
ANKRD23 1553366_s_at    ankyrin repeat domain 23 /// ankyrin repeat domain 39, ANKRD23 /// ANKRD39
$
```

The inner `sed` command converts the `string_file.txt` file into a series of `sed` commands; the output of the inner `sed` is:

```
s/.*\(\<DEFB106A\>\).*/\1 &/
s/.*\(\<ZXFGH456\>\).*/\1 &/
s/.*\(\<ANKRD23\>\).*/\1 &/
s/.*\(\<FNTDRE2433\>\).*/\1 &/
```

The `\<` and `\>` are the old-school notation that some versions of `sed` support to mark beginning and end of words.  In practice, you could probably do without those unless you need to search for words which are also substrings of another word in the list (so, if you needed to search for `ABCD` and `ABCDEF`, the end markers are necessary).

This `sed` script output is provided to the outer `sed` via process substitution and post-processes the output of the `grep` (`grep -F` is equivalent to `fgrep`) to generate the desired output.

If multiple terms could appear on a single line, they'll all be pushed to the front.  There are ways around that if it is a problem, but they aren't particularly neat (though most of the problem comes from using `sed` to generate a `sed` script).

Tested on an Ubuntu 14.04 derivative.